# Any disadvantages for no companions?

Tags: fallout-4

I love how you can have a multitude of companions in this game that all give you perks and things.

I've also heard that bringing certain companions with you can trigger small scenes here and there.

However, I love to take my time, be very carefully around each corner, and companions just ruin all my sneaking attempts, so I don't use them :(...

I have the lone wanderer perk, so IMO it makes up for the carry weight that a companion can bring, and let's suppose that I have maxed all my character perks so I don't need things like lock picking and hacking, in that case, what are all the disadvantages (which cannot be made up for) does never brining any companions with me give my character?

Comment: Quick note: once you pick up a perk from a companion, it's permanent, whether you travel with them or not or even infuriate them.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I use my companions to often draw aggro when fighting a bunch of enemies at once or to transport power armor around for me without use cores.

Comment: You'll miss out on the great fun of them standing in the middle of a doorway as you try to walk through it.

Comment: @Mego ohh i haven't missed it, what do you think i meant by "ruin all my sneaking attempts"? I've had more than my fair share of issues with companions that have made me not play with them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Once you've removed their utility, companions are good for being travel companions.

1) Companions have random dialogue triggers. I was with Nick in Diamond city, and he and a random resident had a conversation about a missing person. On the Prydwen, he had a few snarky comebacks to the Brotherhood scribes on his condition. CVRIE humorously misinterprets Railroad slang. In many major quests, companions have slots for dialogue when you're talking to an NPC.

2) Companions provide firepower. Have you ever wanted to storm into a building with two gatling lasers? Hand one to a companion that can use weapons.

3) Companions give you presents. Dogmeat will bring you items. CVRIE will craft stimpacks for you.

4) Romantic companions give you a large XP boost. Instead of well rested (+10% XP, allied beds only), you get the Lover's Embrace perk (+15% XP, any bed).

5) Humanoid companions can transport power armor. This sometimes gets dicey with quest dialogue lockouts, but companions make good mobile armor stands.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I would add is that Dogmeat currently doesn't count as a companion for the purposes of Lone Wanderer (and a large percentage of the community is certain that's a bug), and the Attack Dog perks are pretty snazzy, so it might be considered suboptimal to NOT have Dogmeat.

Comment: @Dallium if you know if there is a way to disable collision between the player and JUST your companion, then i would be all for it, honestly they get in the way ALL.THE.TIME

Comment: I believe I accidentally toggled clipping on my follower a while back. Try selecting them in the console, and typing `tcl`. You should be able to walk through them.

Comment: [Well Rested](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested) is 10% and [Lover's Embrace](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lover's_Embrace) is 15%

Comment: Point 4 is actually a bigger deal than you make it sound - you only get the Well Rested perk when sleeping in an owned bed (so a bed in a settlement you are allied with, or in a rented bed at an inn).  Random beds in destroyed buildings or raider camps, etc, do NOT provided the Well Rested perk, but sleeping in ANY bed with a romantic companion around gives you the Lover's Embrace perk.

Comment: This is what I get for trying to remember perks from memory.

Comment: Note that the NPC just needs to be near you to get Lover's Embrace.  They don't have to be your current companion.   You can leave them at a small settlement and you'll often get the bonus by sleeping there even if they aren't your current companion.

Answer (score 7):

You'll miss the companion quests, which can be interesting. Each companion has a quest that you can't access otherwise.

You're also missing the companion perks, each one has a unique perk that you can only get by getting your companions to idolize you.

Comment: OP already has the companion perks.   Which means OP has already done the companion quests, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> companions just ruin all my sneaking attempts, so I don't use them :(...

You could take [Cait](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cait) as your companion.  She is the only companion who does not affect your sneak rating.

Another option, if you're on PC, is the [Companions Can Sneak](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5612/?) mod.

> This mod re-makes all vanilla companions so that they do not affect your stealth meter(Sneaking).

Comment: This is not really answering the full question, its an addition to other answers, you could make this a comment. He was not asking for any mods/alternative options either.

Comment: @AshwinGupta: No, this is an acceptable answer.  It does not answer the literal question that was asked in the title, but it does solve the problem OP presented.  Typically those are the sort of answers that are preferred, so I don't understand the downvotes, unless you only read the title and not the question-content.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft to be fair to my question, in the meat, i do ask explicitly "what are all the disadvantages (which cannot be made up for) does never brining any companions with me give my character?" so I'm looking for something more than a solution to the reason that motivated this question.